# Declaring a class with microchip xc8 compiler

Tags: c, class, pic, xc8

I was trying to declare a class in a library for a  projects using xc8 compiler in free mode and the pic16f876a. But it seems that xc8 compiler doesn't accept or
compiles classes...

Is this true? If not, can somebody post an example?

Thanks!!

Comment: What error is reported?

Comment: C does not have classes. Read a C book or tutorial.

Comment: If I can`t use classes and c++ code then why is there the option of c++ main and header files when you try to add a new file??

Comment: @Franz95 If you're using MPLAB or MPLAB X, that's a generic IDE for all of the PIC range. There is a C++ compiler for 32-bit PIC micros, so the option is there to cover everything. It's not smart enough to limit your options, but XC8 (and XC16) are both C, not C++.

Answer (score 5):

There are no classes in the paid compiler, either.  XC8 is an ANSI C compiler, not a C++ compiler.

You get structs in C, but no member functions ("methods"), constructors, or destructors, and all member variables are "public".

To answer the question in comment, the compiler appears to be ANSI, with the sole documented exception (a huge one):

> "Due to limited memory and no hardware
>   implementation of a data stack, recursion is not supported and functions are not reentrant." -- MPLAB XC8 C Compiler User's Guide [5.2.1]

I found the guide [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52053B.pdf).

I can't see any comments in their samples, but I assume that ANSI means no // comments, no variable length arrays, no extended integer and float types.  I also don't see the use of much of  on a PIC, so "ANSI C" probably refers only to the language and not the standard library.

Comment: Not exactly ANSI.. It has some extensions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Doesn't every C compiler?  The ANSI C description is directly from their user's guide, which I take to mean that C99 and later are not supported.

Comment: Is that still ANSI-only? Not even C99? One should not use that anymore.

Comment: @Olaf I agree, but Microsoft's Visual C++ still doesn't support C99 when compiling C code, so you do have to deal with ANSI.  There's nothing really wrong with C89/C90 for embedded use, though.  Mostly, just remembering /* */ for comments.

Comment: "... so you do have to deal with ANSI" or use a compiler supporting the only **valid** standard (C11) or at least the previous one which is more than 16 years old now - C99. You do not drive a Model-T anymore, right? Or write your texts in hyroglyphics. Or use medieval English. (Yes, I'm not very forgiving in that aspect). Btw: It is very unlikely that PIC code will ever be run on Windows (or Linux).

Comment: @MikeHousky FWIW, you can use `//` comments in XC8 and XC16 - I do it as a matter of course